# ImportHTML #VALUE! error for specific URL

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I'm trying to get the data from [http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/](http://wodindex.wikispaces.com) into my spreadsheets. Also from a different subdomain of [wikispaces.com](https://www.wikispaces.com/) the grabbing doesn't work.

Trying to get data from this site gives me a `#VALUE!` error, while the same formula used with another URL (Wikipedia) does work.

What causes this error? Is this site somehow protected?

MWE: `=ImportHTML("http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/";"list";1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `wodindex.wikispaces.com` attempts to store a cookie, and then do some fancy redirect tricks, for reasons I don't know. The functionality behind `ImportHTML` needs to work as a browser (or at least an HTTP client), and probably does not support cookies.

This is what I get from running `wget http://wodindex.wikispaces.com`:

```
--12:41:12--  http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/
           => `index.html'
Resolving wodindex.wikispaces.com... done.
Connecting to wodindex.wikispaces.com[75.126.104.177]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5 [fol
lowing]
--12:41:13--  https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5
           => `auth@authToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5'
Resolving session.wikispaces.com... done.
Connecting to session.wikispaces.com[208.43.192.33]:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/?responseToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5 [following]

--12:41:14--  http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/?responseToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5
           => `index.html@responseToken=f7a1a3abdd9511c29392cf7000b27dd5'
Connecting to wodindex.wikispaces.com[75.126.104.177]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/ [following]
http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/: Redirection cycle detected.

C:\Users\viramd>wget http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/
--12:42:28--  http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/
           => `index.html'
Resolving wodindex.wikispaces.com... done.
Connecting to wodindex.wikispaces.com[75.126.104.177]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8 [fol
lowing]
--12:42:28--  https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8
           => `auth@authToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8'
Resolving session.wikispaces.com... done.
Connecting to session.wikispaces.com[208.43.192.33]:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/?responseToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8 [following]

--12:42:29--  http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/?responseToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8
           => `index.html@responseToken=2141639d8901c291dc288a940c9609e8'
Connecting to wodindex.wikispaces.com[75.126.104.177]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/ [following]
http://wodindex.wikispaces.com/: Redirection cycle detected.
```

As can be seen here, the request is redirected to `session.wikispaces.com`, which has some kind of redirect loop, that can never end.

One 'solution' to your problem is to save the contents of `wodindex.wikispaces.com` to another web server, and fetch it from there. But I'm not sure that would be entirely legal.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your findings and was successful at it !!

The only logical conclusion I can think off, is that the site doesn't use the following tags:

*LIST*:

- `<UL>`
- `<OL>`
- `<DL>`

*TABLE*:

- `<TABLE>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacob,

I've rechecked the source, and it's all there: 

[  <table>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
        <th>Tags</th>
                <td style="white-space: normal;">
...]

Someone reported he couldn't access the source of the site from a mobile device; is it some kind of security issue with the site?